# knockout : table in each option in drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want have table with two columns in each `<option>` in me `<select>`.
I tried this [JSFIDDLE-source](http://jsfiddle.net/engXh/). But bindings in `<span>` isn't working

```
<span data-bind="text : countryName"></span>
<span data-bind="text : selectedCountry"></span>
```

Any ideas? Or another solution?

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't style the contents of a  you can use something like Twitter's excellent [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html) framework for a similar effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/marrok/QdjPt/

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span class="name" data-bind="text: selectedItem().name"></span>
    <span class="desc" data-bind="text: selectedItem().desc"></span>    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul class="list dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: items ">
      <!-- I should be able to use 'click' here but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. -->
      <li class="item" data-bind="event: {mouseover : function(){$root.selectedIndex($index())}}">      
          <span class="name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
          <span class="desc" data-bind="text: desc"></span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var Thing = function(name, desc) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.desc = ko.observable(desc);
};

var AppModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Thing(1, "Thing One"),
        new Thing(2, "Thing Two"),
        new Thing(3, "Thing Three"),
        new Thing(4, "Thing Four")]);
    self.selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.items()[self.selectedIndex()];
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppModel());​
```